# High latency on connecting to my router

Tags: wireless-networking, router, ping

I've just changed my home, now I rent a room in a new place and I am facing an issue with an internet connection. The speed test shows that its roughly 9M download and around 1M upload which is enough for me.
[SpeedTest result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0HLtp.png).
But I my everyday experience shows that the internet connection is slow. So I turned toward the unusual curve of the upload in the SpeedTest resuts.

I checked my ping. With a use of http://whatsmyrouterip.com/ I learned my router's IP address and I pinged it. Here is the result.

```
pawel@Pawel:~$ ping 192.168.1.1
PING 192.168.1.1 (192.168.1.1) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 192.168.1.1: icmp_seq=4 ttl=64 time=2064 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.1.1: icmp_seq=5 ttl=64 time=1063 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.1.1: icmp_seq=6 ttl=64 time=41.3 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.1.1: icmp_seq=7 ttl=64 time=244 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.1.1: icmp_seq=8 ttl=64 time=24.3 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.1.1: icmp_seq=9 ttl=64 time=16.7 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.1.1: icmp_seq=10 ttl=64 time=17.1 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.1.1: icmp_seq=11 ttl=64 time=18.9 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.1.1: icmp_seq=12 ttl=64 time=12.7 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.1.1: icmp_seq=13 ttl=64 time=12.9 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.1.1: icmp_seq=14 ttl=64 time=11.9 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.1.1: icmp_seq=15 ttl=64 time=20.5 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.1.1: icmp_seq=16 ttl=64 time=11.9 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.1.1: icmp_seq=17 ttl=64 time=20.5 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.1.1: icmp_seq=18 ttl=64 time=30.4 ms
```

The initial 2s or 1s is present in all tests. I think that I am fine with some 50ms latency but 2s is really annoying.

Can you suggest me what can be the issue?

I can only access the network through WiFi. I use ubuntu 19.04.

Thanks!

**edit Sep 27 2019**

I have performed some tests and here is an update. My housemates seems not to experience this problem at all. They use macs and a windows machine. There were moments when, they had a perfect connection and I didn't have a connection at all.

This is another element which I would like to add. There are moments when I am connected to the wi-fi and still the pages just keep on staying in the loading state without showing any progress in loading. Would you recommend any additional tests?

Comment: It sounds like WiFi trouble. Have you done anything to troubleshoot your WiFi? Moved closer to the router? Tried a different channel on the router? Used 5Ghz instead of 2.4Ghz? Analyzed the nearby wireless spectrum for interference? Updated router firmware? Updated WiFi adapter drivers? Tested device on any other WiFi network? Tested WiFi on any other device? Looked for any sources of nearby interference (phones, microwaves, other electronics)?

Comment: There are a number of reasons that could cause a high latency. The probable places to start are (1) name resolution, how is that being handled? Do you get your IP dhcp, where? Is the router handing out the address or do you have some server? Or, is your IP fixed? (note: pinging your remote IP from within your LAN can be problematic), (2) do you have IPv4 and/or IPv6 configured? Does your ISP? (3) Interference and channel selection. Generally routers are set in `auto channel selection` mode, but you can configure this manually if needed. There are tools to check the congestion.

Comment: So you are with Linux? Likely that the driver for the wireless adapter simply sucks...If it's an "in-tree" driver you may want to use a distro with a more updated kernel. It might help. If it's out-of-tree / binary blob you may want to see if there's a more updated fork / version.